# what should be in tnsnames.ora and sqlnet.ora for a local database?

Tags: oracle

here is my tnsnames.ora file

```
    # Every line that begins with # is a comment line
#
# Create Oracle net service names, or aliases, for each database server 
# you need to connect to.
#
# TNSNames.ora sample entry
#
# alias =
#  (DESCRIPTION =
#    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = myserver.mycompany.com)(PORT = 1521))
#    (CONNECT_DATA =
#      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
#      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
#    )
#  )
#
# You can modify the entry below for your own database.
# <data source alias> = Name to use in the connection string Data Source
# <hostname or IP> = name or IP of the database server machine
# <port> = database server machine port to use
# <database service name> = name of the database service on the server

ORA_DB =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = khurram)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = ORA_DB)
    )
  )
```

and here is my sqlnet.ora file

```
# Every line that begins with # is a comment line
# You can modify the entry below for your own database.

# sqlnet.ora Network Configuration File

SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS)
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)
```

please help me out here. i dont understand where is the prob. i am getting this error

ora-12154 tns could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Comment: Is your listener running? What does `lsnrctl status` show? What is the service name of your Oracle instance? Does the name resolution work for `khurram` (what does `ping khurram` return?). Is your Oracle instance running?

Comment: What is the connect string you are using, please?